# Correct MySQL Structure for a Time Range for Query Optimization?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a scenario where I want to be able to SELECT rows from a MySQL table, but exclude rows where the current time-of-day is inside a time-range.

**Example**:
The "quiet" period for one row is 10pm - 8:30am.
My SQL SELECT statement should not return that row if the current server time is after 10pm or before 8:30am.

**Example 2**: The "quiet period" is NULL and ignored.

**Example 3**: A new row is created with a quiet period from 9:53am to 9:55am. If the current server time is in that 2-minute window, the row is not returned by the SELECT.

**My question**:
What data format would you use in the database, and how would you write the query?

I have thought about a few different approaches (defining start_time as one column and duration as another, defining both in seconds... or using Date stamps... or whatever). None of them seem ideal and require a lot of calculation.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you only need the time for each row or do you also need the date?

Comment: I don't need to return either. I'm just trying to filter based on time of day. I don't care about date. As with my example above: I want to exclude rows where the current server time-of-day is inside the specified "quiet window."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would store the start and end dates as MySQL native [TIME](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/time.html) fields.
You would need to consider ranges that span midnight as two separate ranges but you would be able to query the table like this, To find all current quiet periods

```
SELECT DISTINCT name FROM `quiet_periods` 
WHERE start_time<=CURTIME() AND CURTIME()<=end_time
```

Or to find all non-active quiet periods

```
SELECT name FROM quiet_periods WHERE name NOT IN (
  SELECT name FROM `quiet_periods` 
  WHERE start_time<=CURTIME() AND CURTIME()<=end_time
)
```

So with sample data

```
id  --  name        -- start_time -- end_time
 1  --  late_night  -- 00:00:00   -- 08:30:00
 2  --  late_night  -- 22:00:00   -- 23:59:59
 3  --  null_period --   NULL     --   NULL
 4  --  nearly_10am -- 09:53:00   -- 09:55:00
```

At 11pm this would return

```
null_period
nearly_10am
```

from the second query.

Depending on performance and how many rows you had you might want to refactor the second query into a JOIN and probably add the relevant INDEXes too.

Comment: Nicely done! Spanning midnight was the problem I was considering, and I was hoping it could be done without adding a 2nd table and doing a JOIN, but oh well =P